# How to write CLOB data into a text file using Informatica

Tags: xml, oracle, clob, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have an xml file which is present in a CLOB column in an Oracle table. I would like to write the content of CLOB column into a LINUX target directory through Informatica. How can this be accomplished. I am sure about parsing the XML files through Informatica but trying to figure out how it can be done in Informatica. Thank you.

Comment: I need to just write the XML content present in CLOB column into a .xml file (using only Informatica).